# Getting an estimate of the form $\lVert u(t+h)-u(t) \rVert_{L^1(\Omega)} \leq \frac{Ch}{t}$ on solution of PDE

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $u$ be a weak solution (i.e. $u \in C([0,T];L^1(\Omega))$ of some degenerate or nondegenerate parabolic equation $u' - Au = f$ on a bounded domain. (For my purpose it is enough to have this for the porous medium equation, in which also $u^m \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$.)

I am seeking a estimate of the form
$$\lVert u(t+h)-u(t) \rVert_{L^1(\Omega)} \leq \frac{Ch}{t}$$
for $h >0$ small (want to send $h$ to zero later). Here $C$ is some constant not depending on $h$, $t$ or $u$. Note that the power of $h$ must be one, not a half.

This type of estimate is useful in order to show time regularity.

**My question is, what techniques are available and can one use to in order to derive such an estimate, apart from the one I describe below?**

I know of one way, which is detailed in the book on PME by Vazquez. This way comes out of rescaling the solution so that it satisfies the PME again with a rescaled initial data and then using the comparison principle after picking the scaling parameter appropriately.

Is there some other method? I'd prefer variational methods and not semigroup.

Why I want to do this? Because I work on a similar such equation where the rescaling I described above doesn't work so I am looking for different methods.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is given by Ph. Bénilan & M. G. Crandall in "Regularizing effects of homogeneous evolution equations", *Contributions to analysis and geometry (Baltimore, Md., 1980), pp. 23–39, Johns Hopkins Univ. Press, Baltimore, Md., 1981.*

They prove this estimate for three PDEs, namely
$$\partial_tu=\partial^2_x(|u|^{\alpha-1}u),\qquad\partial_tu=\partial_x(|u|^{\alpha-1}u),\qquad\partial_tu=\partial_x(|\partial_x u|^{\alpha-1}\partial_x u).$$
A crucial point is that the equation admits a scaling invariance group. I presume that it is the way it is presented in Vazquez' book.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for late response. Yes, that is how it is done in Vazquez's book so I was hoping to see a different approach when such scaling is not available.